# Flutter-Push notification should not show when user is in chatroom specially in iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Push notification is integrated using firebase in the flutter app. I am getting a notification when I am in the same chatroom, it should be like when we are in a chatroom we should not get any type of notification for that specific chatroom. We can have a notification for another userChatID. It is working fine in Android but not on iPhone. Please do suggest an alternative for overlay.

Here is a piece of code in the main. dart:

```
   await FirebaseMessaging.instance
       .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
       alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
```

in ChatRoom.dart

```
var androidInitilize =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
var iOSinitilize = new IOSInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification
    );
var initilizationsSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitilize, iOS: iOSinitilize);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initilizationsSettings,
        onSelectNotification: null);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification.android;
      if (notification != null) {
        if (android != null) {
          String userChatID = message.data["userchatId"];
          if (userChatID.toString() != activeCurrentUserChatID) {
            flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                notification.hashCode,
                notification.title,
                notification.body,
                NotificationDetails(
                  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                    Platform.isAndroid
                        ? 'com.xyz
                        : 'com.xyz',
                    "xyz",
                    //      one that already exists in example app.
                    icon: null,
                  ),
                ));

            // _showNotification(message.data["title"], message.data["body"]);
          }
        }

        else {
          String userChatID = message.data["userchatId"];
          if (userChatID.toString() != activeCurrentUserChatID) {

            flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                notification.hashCode,
                notification.title,
                notification.body,
                NotificationDetails(
                  iOS:IOSNotificationDetails(
                      presentAlert: true,  
                      presentBadge: false, 
                      presentSound: true, 
                      badgeNumber: 0,
                      subtitle: "Hello", 
                  )
                ));
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Chatroom.dart shouldn't house the notifications listener. You should move that function to a main widget that can show notifications regardless of any page. To hide notifications on certain page it's a good idea to manage that in the state i.e. save the current page in an app state that can be access anywhere and check what page the user is currently in for ex.

```
if (state.currentPage == 'ChatSCreen' || state.currentPage == 'SettingsScreen') {
    return;
}

flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show();
```

and whenever you navigate to a new page set the currentPage in the state.

Comment: I agreed, but here I am facing one problem. In iOS flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(); is also called after (default notification) from firebase. My question is lets take one example: (A) and (B) user are chatting in (AB Chatroom) so definitely as both are chatting currently they should not get notification of each other. Right? Here I am getting notification of (A) and (B) user when they are chatting in (AB Chatroom). we should get notification other then (A) and (B) user. This problem is only occuring in iOS. and I will consider your point too.

Comment: Are you sending the notification to a channel or to their tokenids?